# Record audio with CaptureSharedEventDriven not set time

Tags: c++, windows, wasapi

In `CaptureSharedEventDriven` recording time is put in `TargetDurationInSec` and they set size of buffer is `size_t captureBufferSize = capturer->SamplesPerSecond() * TargetDurationInSec * capturer->FrameSize()`
How to record audio without `TargetDurationInSec` instead I press the key combination when finished. Thanks for help.

Comment: The sample needs some amount of changes. Instead of copying to a fixed sized buffer (CopyMemory in CWASAPICapture::DoCaptureThread()), write the data to a sink, as demonstrated in the sample code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream the MyAudioSink can well write to a file

Comment: Hello @SimonMourier Can you help me code? I don't understand this well. Thanks you.